# Cannot add printer in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, printer

After navigating to `Windows Settings > Devices > Printers & scanners`, when I click `Add a printer or scanner`, nothing happens. Windows Settings shuts down, no window or wizard pops up. My account has administrative rights.

Also get the same result (nothing is displayed) from:

- `Control Panel > Devices and Printers > Add a printer`
- From an administrator command prompt, `rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /il`

Is there service that needs to be running? Can you launch the `Add printer wizard` manually?

#### Update

Still no solution to the above question, but have managed to get my printer working as follows:

- Download the [HP drivers for Windows 10](https://support.hp.com/gb-en/document/c04675396)
- In my case, the printer is an older LaserJet 4050 which requires the [HP Universal Print Driver for Windows](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/UPD/4157320/model/4157320)
- Running this download allowed me to select `Traditional mode` and to browse to the printer on the network
- After completing the installation, the printer now works

The above may not work for non-HP models. Would still like to understand what is stopping the Windows `Add printer` from working.

Comment: Does it also not work in `system control`? `system control > devices and printer > add printer`

Comment: @SimonS: Yes, same result. Have updated the question with this information, thanks.

Comment: Control panel! that was the word i was searching for. maybe you could try a `sfc /scannow` from an elevated cmd, that could already fix the problem

Answer (score 2):

The "Device Association Service" is required for the Printer Wizard to function in Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks! Saved my day!
(the Windows 10 trouble shooter on printers is not finding/fixing this)